# Telegram Api - is there a way to add people to a channel/group using phone number instead username?

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot

Actually my script can add people to group, using username. I wonder if it's possible to do the same using phone number.. Telegram api is not clarely about that. Thanks :)